# Clearing SOLR 7.1 index

Tags: solr

I have been using SOLR 4.10.2, and am getting ready to migrate to 7.1

Under 4.10.2 I was able to clear an index with the following:

```
var address = @"http://mysolrserver:8983/solr/mysolrcore/update?stream.body=<delete><query>(*:*)</query></delete>&commit=true";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadString(address).Dump();
```

When I try this against a SOLR 7.1 server, I get a response 400 - Bad request.

```
{
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Stream Body is disabled. See http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/requestdispatcher-in-solrconfig.html for help",
    "code":400}}
```

I went into solrconfig.xml for the core and set the  element to

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
                multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>
```

but I still get the same error.

Since 7.1 is now json by default, I have tried adding

```
&wt=xml
```

to the end of the url, but I get the same result: 400 - Bad Request

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're switching the wrong parameter. If you want to allow `stream.body` in the URL, you have to set `enableStreamBody="true"`. `enableRemoteStreaming` controls `stream.file` and `stream.url` which can be used to read from remote locations.

Comment: In [the requestParsers section](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/requestdispatcher-in-solrconfig.html) as shown above, which is a sub element of `requestDispatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

I run below call in postman, after deleting query working fine.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/CORENAME/config -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d'{
    "set-property" : {"requestDispatcher.requestParsers.enableRemoteStreaming":true},
    "set-property" : {"requestDispatcher.requestParsers.enableStreamBody":true}
}'
```